# How to fix label texts when exporting .mxd to pdf?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, labeling, export, pdf

I have exported an .mxd to pdf but once I open the pdf, most of my text labels are mis-represented (altered in someway). This is the first time I've had this issue.
- What I did when creating the map was change labels to annotations and changed font style and size.
Note: one of my layers' labels show up just fine but the other is in some unrecognizable font, this includes the tables in the map.

Any helpful suggestions?

Comment: Good question. Exporting to pdf can mess with labels and with colors. It can mess with a lot of things, actually. I never figured out what causes it. +1 for the question.

Comment: I have had the same problem when exporting maps with annotation to pdf. For instance, I have some county highway shield annotation (ddv TrueType font, embedded in export) that just turn into black squares after exporting. I haven't been able to figure out why this happens for the longest time.

Comment: Are you embedding the fonts when exporting the PDF?

Comment: From ArcGIS Help under Exporting to PDF, I read that some fonts do not support embedding and will not embed even when this option is checked.

Comment: Question is which fonts are supported and which aren't?

Comment: There's no list because it's a font by font property set by the creator. http://support.esri.com/ja/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/28548 talks about checking the specific font you're using. Typically purchased fonts and custom ones that come with some programs cannot be embedded.

Comment: Ok, thanks to all for your comments. I will go ahead and keep fonts as arial.

Comment: Curved placement tends to destroy text, avoid using it if at all possible... not just in export to PDF but printing, it can look great on the screen but print like junk! If you have Adobe software you can try export to AI format which doesn't seem so bad and then use Illustrator to PDF the files. This is a long standing problem - I first logged a support request in v 9.0 which still has not been fixed. There is an ArcScript that converts text to poly (again not for curved text). Knowing that text placement isn't exact I try to place it such that a bit of movement is allowed.

Comment: @Knteza It sounds like you are planning to use Arial fonts as a workaround.  However, if you are wanting to try and solve rather than workaround the specific issue that you encountered then I think you should **edit** your question to improve it with perhaps: two pictures showing text appearance in MXD and PDF, text properties of the labels you are using, version of ArcGIS for Desktop, etc.

Answer (score 3):

When you export to PDF, on the second tab of the "Options" you will see a box that will most likely be unchecked: "Embed All Document Fonts"  Make sure that it is checked and it should reduce those errors for the people viewing your PDFs.  If you yourself are seeing those errors, then something else is going haywire because those fonts should already be installed on your machine.  I hope this helps.